# Get the least squares straight line for a set of points

Tags: python

For a set of points, I want to get the straight line that is the closest approximation of the points using a least squares fit.

I can find a lot of overly complex solutions here on SO and elsewhere but I have not been able to find something simple. And this should be very simple.

```
x = np. array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np. array([23, 31, 42, 43 ])
slope, intercept = leastSquares(x, y)
```

Is there some library function that implements the above leastSquares()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.linalg.lstsq` can compute such a fit for you.  There is an example in the documentation that does exactly what you need.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq

To summarize it here …

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> y = np.array([-1, 0.2, 0.9, 2.1])
>>> A = np.stack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T

>>> m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
>>> m, c
(1.0 -0.95) # may vary
```

Comment: What is the purpose of A = np.stack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T? TIA

Comment: `A = np.stack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T` rearranges the `x` coordinates to match the format expected by the `lstsq` function.  It is essentially treating each coordinate as the equation `m*x + c = y`.  This is expressed by the multiplication between A, which has two columns … the first column is the x coordinates, the second column is all ones.  When matrix multiplied by `y`, this yields a vector having the above equation for each `x, y` coordinate.

Comment: So [x, np.ones(len(x))] gives me [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1]]. Then np.stack() puts these pairs of numbers into a stack. And .T transposes the stack. Correct? And then the big question - WHY? It seems like a very complex transformation for something that should be very simple.

Comment: Correct, the line creates a 4-row, 2-column matrix, where the first column are the x coordinates and the second column is all ones.  This is required because `lstsq` works with the equation `A @ c = y`, where `@` denotes matrix multiplication.  `c` will be the 1 by 2 matrix `[m, b]`, which are the slope and offset, and `y` will have one row and as many columns as there are coordinates (4 in this example). Because of how matrix multiplication is defined, this means each element of `y` will be equal to `m*x + b` for the corresponding `x` coordinate, which is what it uses to minimize residuals

Comment: It seems to me that Python always wants everything to be a general purpose matrix operation whenever possible. It adds a bit of complexity in this case, but hey - it gets the job done. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, I think for an ordinary least squares fit with a single line you can derive a closed-form solution for the coefficients, if I'm not utterly mistaken. Though there's some pitfalls with numerical stability.

If you look for least squares in general, you'll find more general and thus more complex solutions, because least squares can be done for many more models than just the linear one.

But maybe the `sklearn` package with its `LinearRegression` model might do easily what you want to do? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

or for more detailed control the `scipy` package, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lstq

# Turn x into 2d array; raise it to powers 0 (for y-axis-intercept)
# and 1 (for the slope part)
M = x[:, np.newaxis] ** [0, 1]

p, res, rnk, s = lstq(M, y)

intercept, slope = p[0], p[1]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of M = x[:, np.newaxis] ** [0, 1]? TIA

Comment: To express the least squares fit as a matrix problem, we need a matrix `M` such that each column of `M` corresponds to one of the relevant powers of `x`. The y-intercept corresponds to power 0, i.e. all 1s. The slope column corresponds to power 1. It achieves the same thing as other answers achieve with the manual stacking of ones and x, but is more general (i.e. if you want to fit a least squares parabola, just do `x[:. np.newaxis] ** [0, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement the least squares regression:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np. array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np. array([23, 31, 42, 43 ])

def leastSquares(x, y):
    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    y = y[:, np.newaxis]
    slope, intercept = np.dot((np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A.T,A)),A.T)),y)
    return slope, intercept

slope, intercept = leastSquares(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse:

```
from scipy import linalg
x = np. array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np. array([23, 31, 42, 43 ])
x = np.array([x, np.ones(len(x))]) 
B = linalg.pinv(x)
sol = np.reshape(y,(1,len(y))) @ B 
slope, intercept = sol[0,0], sol[0,1]
```